# How do I change the background image based on input fields being blank/nonblank using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I've got a form with 5 search criteria input boxes on it. I received an additional requirement to have a "Clear All" button on the page to clear the input boxes.

I would like to have the "Clear All" button actually be a `div` with a background image that has a gray background when the input boxes are empty, and has a red background when they have something in them.

Clicking on the "Clear All" button will clear the input boxes.

I've gotten almost everything working, except for the toggle to the red background image when the user types something in the search boxes.  I built a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/27896/ that shows my problem (I used background-color, instead of a background-image, to eliminate unnecessary stuff).

The JavaScript in my jsfiddle matches what I want to do, and looks like this:

```
function clearSearchClick() {
    $('.ui-clear').removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');
    $(':input').val('');
    $('.first').focus();
}

function docKeyPress(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('pretend I searched');
    }
}

function searchEmpty() {
    var valid = true;
    $(':input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') return false;
    });
    return valid;    
}

function inputKeyUp(event) {
    if (!searchEmpty()) {
        $('ui-clear.disabled').removeClass('disabled').addClass('enabled');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('.first').focus();
    $('.ui-clear').click(clearSearchClick);
    $(':input').keyup(inputKeyUp);
    $(document).keypress(docKeyPress);
});
```

I know the following about the JavaScript:

1. The `.first` focus works
2. The `.ui-clear` click handler works

I'm not getting the black box to the left of the first search box to turn red when the user types something.  I would appreciate any insight on correct, efficient ways to accomplish this goal.

Comment: `$('document')` is invalid, don't quote `document`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, updated both the jsfiddle and the question, but that doesn't actually get at my problem which seems to more in the `inputKeyUp()` function.

Comment: look at errors in console...`keyUp` should be lower case

Comment: @charlietfl fixed the keyup, (these are actually just typos as I put it into jsfiddle.  I've updated my jsfiddle, but it still doesn't update to red when I type in a textbox.  I'm new at jsfiddle, is there a console there that would show errors?

Comment: use your browser console. Not sure what should happen in UI  so not totally clear what issue is. Also any updates you saved in fiddle should change url in question to reflect them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be over-complicating things...

If I understand things correctly, you want the appearance of a div (based on an applied class) to change if any inputs in a form contain user entered text?

You also want to do this on a keyup event rather than a change?

So, I'd do something like this

First set the default (black) background in the class that is applied to the div

```
.ui-clear {
    border: thin black outset;
    height: 24px;
    width:24px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}
```

and a class for 'enabled'

```
.enabled {
    background-color: red;
}
```

That's really all you need in styles to make this work

Then the code - again, keep it simple

```
$(function () {
    $('.first').focus();
    $('.search input:text').keyup(function(){
        var allCrit="";
        $('.search input:text').each(function(){
            allCrit += $(this).val();
        });
        $('.ui-clear').toggleClass("enabled", allCrit != "");         
    });
});
```

What are we doing here?

1. Capture the keyup event for each input box
2. Iterate through them and concatenate each val into a string
3. Test whether the string contains anything and if it does, toggle the enabled class